# Enable IIS SMTP Service on Azure instances

Tags: azure

Is it possible to enable IIS SMTP Service on Azure instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this very same conversation with someone at Microsoft just the other day.

Azure doesn't support the SMTP service because if it did, it would quickly become the world's biggest spamming engine and the Azure IP address range would soon be blacklisted.

The answer I was given is to relay through an on-premise or third-party SMTP relay service.

You might be able to achieve something with a VM Role, or maybe a different SMTP solution in a worker role, but for the reasons given above, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: +1. Steve Marx (http://blog.smarx.com/), one of the leads on the Azure team, makes this same suggestion.

Comment: Role instances [do support the IIS6 SMTP service](http://nicoploner.blogspot.se/2011/10/sending-e-mails-using-iis-smtp-server.html). As long as you don't contact target SMTP servers directly from role instances, but relay instead, the local IIS6 SMTP service is a viable alternative.